# An Awk program to find all primes till N

Tags: awk

I developed Awk code to print all primes till N where N is given as command line argument. I think I took pretty much all the optimizations into account. Could someone help if it could be optimized even more. The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
  for (i=oddify(ARGV[1]); i>2; i=i-2){
    flag=1 #prime
    for(j=3; j<=ceil(sqrt(i)); j=j+2){
      if (i%j==0){
        flag=0 #not prime
        break
      }
    }
    if (flag==1){printf("%d\n", i) }
  }
  printf("2\n")
}

function ceil(n){
  return (n == int(n)) ? n : int(n)+1
}

function oddify(n){
  return (n%2 != 0) ? n : n-1
}
```

How to run: `awk -f prime.awk 10000`

Answer (score 1):

Bug: when I run the program with argument 1, it prints 2 even though 2 > 1.

The code is not optimized at all. It computes `ceil` and `sqrt` way too often, in a way that is obvious to optimize. All other prime programs on this site already do that, have a look at them.

The code is not optimized enough. It contains `i = i + 2`, which should have been `i += 2` from the beginning. A third of these calls can be omitted using the standard prime searching technique that has been mentioned more than enough on this site.

The variable name `flag` is terrible. It should be `is_prime` instead.

Having the most interesting code in the `BEGIN` block is bad design. You should define a function `is_prime` and another function `print_primes_up_to`. This allows you to declare `i` and `j` as local variables.

In the function `ceil`, the parameter name `n` is confusing since this name implies to the human reader that it is a natural number. In reality it is a floating point number though. A better name for this variable is `x`.

The code is missing some documentation. It should clearly state up to which number it reports correct results. It should also state the first number for which a wrong result is printed. Internally, many AWK implementations use 64-bit floating point numbers, therefore I guess this number is somewhere around \$2^{53}\$.